# What is the benefit of using a custom class over a map?

Tags: java

I have some piece of code that returns a min and max values from some input that it takes. I need to know what are the benefits of using a custom class that has a minimum and maximum field over using a map that has these two values?

```
//this is the class that holds the min and max values
public class MaxAndMinValues {
   private double minimum;
   private double maximum;

   //rest of the class code omitted
}

//this is the map that holds the min and max values
Map<String, Double> minAndMaxValuesMap
```

Comment: maybe you will soon need a new field `average` ?

Comment: How do you store `min` **AND** `max` value in the `Map<String, Double>` for the same key ?

Comment: @AxelH I assume min and max are the keys

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Oooooww, I didn't read his question like that.

Answer (score 1):

The most apparent answer would be Object Oriented Programming aspects like the possibility to data with functionality, and the possibility to derive that class.

But let's for the moment assume, that is not a major factor, and your example is so simplistic, that I wouldn't use a `Map` either. What I would use is the `Pair` class from Apache Commons: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html

(ImmutablePair):
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/ImmutablePair.html

The `Pair` class is generic, and has two generic types, one for each field. You can basically define a Pair of something, and get type safety, IDE support, autocompletion, and the big benefit of knowing what is inside. Also a `Pair` features stuff that a Map can not. For example, a `Pair` is potentially Comparable. See also `ImmutablePair`, if you want to use it as key in another `Map`.

```java
public Pair<Double, Double> foo(...) {
    // ...
    Pair<Double, Double> range = Pair.of(minimum, maximum);
    return range;
}
```

The big advantage of this class is, that the type you return exposes the contained types. So if you need to, you could return different types from a single method execution (without using a map or complicated inner class).

e.g. `Pair<String, Double>` or `Pair<String, List<Double>>`...

Answer (score 0):

In simple situation, you just need to store `min` and `max` value from user input, your custom class will be ok than using `Map`, the reason is: in Java, a `Map` object can be a `HashMap`, `LinkedHashMap` or and `TreeMap`. it get you a short time to bring your data into its structure and also when you get value from the object. So in simple case, as you just described, just need to use your custom class, morever, you can write some method in your class to process user input, what the Map could not process for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to look from perspective of the usage of a programming language. Let it be any language, there will be multiple ways to achieve the result (easy/bad/complicated/performing ...). Considering an Object oriented language like java, this question points more on to the design side of your solution.

> Think of accessibility.

The values in a Map is kind of public that , you can modify the contents as you like from any part of the code. If you had a condition that the min and max should be in the range [-100 ,100] & if some part of your code inserts a 200 into map - you have a bug. Ok we can cover it up with a validation , but how many instances of validations would you write? But an Object ? there is always the encapsulation possibilities.

> Think of re-use

. If you had the same requirement in another place of code, you have to rewrite the map logic again(probably with all validations?) Doesn't look good right?

> Think of extensibility

. If you wanted one more data like median or average -either you have to dirty the map with bad keys or create a new map. But a object is always easy to extend.

So it all relates to the design. If you think its a one time usage probably a map will do ( not a standard design any way. A map must contain one kind of data technically and functionally)

Last but not least, think of the **code readability and cognitive complexity**. it will be always better with objects with relevant responsibilities than unclear generic storage.

Hope I made some sense!

Answer (score 0):

The benefit is simple : make your code clearer and more robust.
The `MaxAndMinValues` name and its class definition (two fields) conveys a min and a max value but overall it makes sure that will accept only these two things and its class API is self explanatory to know how to store/get values from it.
While `Map<String, Double> minAndMaxValuesMap` conveys also the idea that a min and a max value are stored in but it has also multiple drawbacks in terms of design :

- we don't know how to retrieve values without looking how these were added.
  About it, how to name the keys we we add entries in the map ? `String` type for  key is too broad. For example "MIN", "min", "Minimum" will be accepted. An enum would solve this issue but not all.
- we cannot ensure that the two values (min and max) were added in (while an arg constructor can do that)
- we can add any other value in the map since that is a Map and not a fixed structure in terms of data.

Beyond the idea of a clearer code in general, I would add that if `MaxAndMinValues` was used only as a implementation detail inside a specific method or in a lambda, using a `Map` or even an array `{15F, 20F}` would be acceptable. But if these data are manipulated through methods, you have to do their meaning the clearest possible.

Answer (score 0):

We used custom class over Hashmap to sort Map based on values part